# Prime twins and $1 \mod 30$ confusion

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, sieve-theory, twin-primes

Jie Wu improved Brun's theorem and showed that the number of prime twins up to $n$ satisfies for sufficiently large $n$ :

$$\pi_2(n) < 4.5 \frac{n}{ln(n)^2} $$

However this confused me while trying to get a good estimate of the prime twins.

I was thinking in terms of $1 \mod 30$.

Consider the integer intervals $[30 k + 10,30 k + 20]$.

between $1$ and a large $n$ this means these intervals have together about $n/3$ integers within them.

When we sieve these intervals the usual way ; $C n (1-2/3)(1-2/5)(1-2/7) ...$

we get the usual estimate $ C n / ln(n)^2 $.

$C$ is here the usual value from the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture divided by $3$ because our intervals have a measure of $1/3$.

However I think primes of the form $30 k + 1$ should not be sieved because multiplying integers times $1 (\mod 30)$ does not change anything ($\mod 30$).

In other words prime twins candidates of the form $30 k + 11, 30 k + 13$ and $30 k + 17,30 k + 19$ (these are in the intervals defined above) are not sieved out by number of the form $30 k + 1$ so we should not sieve primes of the form $30 k + 1$.

Assuming that logic is correct my estimate became :

$T(n) = C n (1-2/3)(1-2/5)...$ where where omit terms of the form $(1-2/q)$ where $q$ is a prime of the form $1 \mod 30$.

Since all primes $> 5$ are of the form $1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29$ mod $30$ , $1 \mod 30$ takes $1/8$ of all primes.

Because of the prime number theorem the product over $(1-2/q)$ is then close to the product over $(1-2/(8p))$ where $p$ are the primes.

We simplify $(1-2/8p) = (1-1/4p) $ hence we get a (correcting) factor around $\ln(n)^{1/4}$.

The estimate $T(n)$ is therefore around $C n \ln(n)^{-2+(1/4)}$ or simplified :

$$T(n) = C n \ln(n)^{-7/4}$$

But this contradicts Brun's theorem and Jie Wu's theorem.

Where did I go wrong ?

Im confused.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't sieve with those numbers. For example, $1271$ is a multiple of $31$, and $1271\equiv 11 \bmod 30$ - if I understand your argument correctly.

Comment: 1271 is 11 mod 30 because its a multiple of 41. If 41 has been used in the sieve ( all multiples of 41 removed ) then there is no need to remove 1271 again.
(41 = 11 mod 30)

Comment: But $41>\sqrt{1271}$, so wouldn't have been sieved?

Comment: That argument only makes sense if 3*1271 <= n. If our n is much larger than 1271 , then 41 is sieved out , as is 1271 because its a multiple of 41.